# How to define QgsVectorLayer by QDomNode?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am using QGIS 2.4, Python 2.7.5, win 8.1.

I am trying to read layers from QGIS project. When I try define QgsVectorLayer using QDomNode and readXML function, following error appears:

```
layer.readXML(layerDOM)
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'readXML'
```

code is here:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

app = QgsApplication([], True)
print app.initQgis()

doc = QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(QFile("composer.qgs"), False)

layers = doc.elementsByTagName("maplayer")

for x in xrange(layers.count()):
    layerDOM = layers.at(x)
    layer = QgsVectorLayer()
    layer.readXML(layerDOM)

app.exitQgis()
```

Does anybody know, why does the error appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method exist but you wrote it uncorrectly

> > > help(QgsVectorLayer.readXml)
> > >       Help on built-in function readXml:

readXml(...)
    QgsVectorLayer.readXml(QDomNode) -> bool

Comment: :) well sorry for that question and thanks a lot! **readXML**-> **readXml**